# Отличия PDO SQLSRV Windows IIS и Linux Apache

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Есть проблема в выборе бинарных данных из таблицы.
Исторически так сложилось, что пароль хранится в поле типа binary(64) в БД MS SQL
Есть скрипт который выбирает пароль, пример:

```
$pdo = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=8.8.8.8;Database=test', 'vova', 'megasecretpassword');
$sql = "SELECT Password FROM users WHERE Email = 'vova@kremlin.ru'";
$res = $pdo->query($sql);
$data = $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($data);
```

Результат в Linux Apache поле password будет такой:

> 55A5560F37D53FCA2DD4DE1032BDC3E1B4A2727C5CAF70 ...

А вот в Windows IIS вот такой:

> U�V7�?�-��2��ᴢr|\�p� ...

Вопрос, что нужно сделать чтобы было везде одинаково? Спасибо!

P.S функция bin2hex приводит вариант из Windows к варианту из Linux

P.P.S сервер MS SQL в обоих случаях один и тот же.

Comment: в какой кодировке отдают контент то сервера? мб надо просто выбирать `select hex(password)` всегда?

Comment: Да хз какая там по умолчанию кодировка в MS SQL (((

Comment: я бы сказал, что виндовз все правильно делает, выводя что есть. если вам надо hex-представление бинарных данных выводить, то выбирайте их через `hex()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я уже написал в комментариях, IIS возвращает вам нормальный результат, печатает полученные бинарные данные, и на экране видим то, что видим. В случае linux почему то драйвер переводит бинарные данные в текстовую форму. Это не корректное поведение, он не должен ничего с ними делать.

Но этим багом вы похоже давно и успешно пользуетесь. Может не конкретно этот, но аналогичный баг описан здесь: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40913 
Цитата из [статьи по теме](http://jeremycook.ca/2010/02/21/handling-binary-data-with-pdo/):

> Unfortunately there’s a bug which means that instead of returning a stream into $lob PDO returns a string containing the binary data.

Описание бага было создано 10 лет назад, и переоткрыто в 2017м году для пхп версии 7. Причем судя по всему, он так и не был пофиксен, в обсуждениях перечислены все версии от 5.2 до 7й, причем упомянаются как nix так и windows системы. С этой точки зрения даже странно, что ваш IIS отдает контент корректно.

В любом случае, поскольку для вашей задачи получить-то надо как раз hex-строку то получайте ее уже на выходе с сервера, например, `select convert(varchar(64),password,2) as password`.

*зы: не проверял*

Comment: Да, я тоже понимаю, что виндовс всё правильно делает.
Т.к это используется всего в 1 месте, то сделал проверку на ОС, и в случае с виндой просто использую функцию bin2hex

Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ!