# Скачивание бинарных данных из БД MS SQL средствами php

Tags: php, sql-server, blob

Добрый день всем. Подсобите пожалуйста с вопросом, который пока не могу решить, поиск в интернете особо не дал ответа. 
Итак есть файлы, которые хранятся в БД MS SQL, в бинарном виде (поле blob). Задача простая, вывести для каждой статьи соответствующее приложение/приложения средствами php.
Итак код, который дает мне какой-то результат.

```
try {
$db = new PDO("odbc:Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=SERVER;Database=mydb; Uid=user;Pwd=1admiN; charset=UTF-8");
    $sql = $db->query("SELECT TOP 1 id, name, ext, file FROM blob_files");
    $row = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch (PDOExeption $e){
    print "error". $e-> getMessage(). "<br/>";
    die();
}
foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
    $filename = $value[name];
    $f = fopen($filename, "w") or die ('Ошибка!');
    $file = fwrite($f, $value[file]);
header("Content-Disposition: attacment; filename=$filename;");
header ("Location: " $filename);
exit(); }
```

Когда файл скачивается (размер вроде соответствует), но при открытии файла, например **.doc**, в ворде отображаются сначала пустые первые 5 строк, а потом весь бинарный код, в виде текста.

Нашел в сети пример где вместо функции `fopen()`, используют функцию `file_put_content()`.
Этой функцией получилось избавиться от первых пяти пустых строк, но увы файл также открывается как текст. Также пробовал все режимы для `fopen()`, не помогло.

Также на просторах вычитал, что MS SQL передает бинарные данные в кодировке ANSI и если надо передавать данные для UTF8, то  писать при подключении надо в какой кодировке следует открывать соединение, но я в этом не разобрался, тем более, что название файлов на кириллице на скачку дает корректно, при этом если сделать `var_dump($row)`- *результат выборки данных из БД*, то там где русскоязычные названии, рисует знаки вопроса в ромбе )).

Короче вокруг одни вопросы, а ответа пока не видно, хотя задачка тревиальная. 
Скажу что проделывая дома, то же самое на MySQL, все работает как надо, в примитивном виде и даже если задать на выборку не 1 строки а 5, то скачивает все 5 файлов, а вот такой фокус на MS SQL не проходит.

*поправка*

Есть такое дело недоглядел, когда  сюда переносил по памяти. Но не поставленная в примере кавычка закрывающая в запросе, сути не меняет. 
Итак, если я ставлю (пишу с телефона, поэтому извиняйте)

```
foreach ($row as $key=>$value){
$filename = $value['Name'];
$fp = fopen($filename, 'wb') or die("Ошибка!");
$file = fwrite($fp, $value['File']) or die ('Error');
header ('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$filename');       header ('Content-type: application/x-force-download;'); 
echo $value['File']; }
```

то он мне выдает файл с расширением, как положено, но первые 5 строк пустые.

Если я пишу тот же цикл, только убираю два хедера внутри и ставлю  **header** после цикла

```
header ('Location: '.$filename);
exit();
```

то он мне выдает файл без пустых строк.
Но в том и другом случае внутри в виде текста бинарный код этого файла.

Comment: приводите код как есть, а не то как тут, без закрывающей кавычки запроса и с комментом главного хэдера

Comment: был тут вопрос недавно, про то что апач выдает блоб поля с sql-server в текстовом hex  виде. буквально с неделю назад.

Comment: хах, чуть ли не месяц прошел. вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/742855/223826 Вопрос изначально как раз  обратный, но речь идет про один и тот же баг.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, но я если честно в этом сильно "плаваю". Вот по примеру из вашего ответа, я перевел бинарные данные в шестнадцатеричные. Каким теперь образом "заставить" их преобразоваться, чтобы файл хранящийся в БД, при скачивании, открылся в исходном формате? Для понимания, работа идет на сервере 2008 IIS7. То есть php общается через IIS7 с БД.

Comment: честно сказать я с этой проблемой не сталкивался. в том моем ответе есть ссылка на статейку, там были решения какие то. Еще можете попробовать установить формат колонки [`PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_BINARY`](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php) или `PDO::PARAM_LOB` как это [обычно делается](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.lobs.php)

Comment: попробовал задать в качестве параметра полю которое содержит бин. код $q->bindColumn(2, PDO::PARAM_LOB, PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_BINARY); показывает ошибку 500

Comment: вы почитайте про второй параметр функции этой. даи про первый, если sql-запрос тот же что в вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, похоже в эпопее с этим вопросом замаячил конец(надеюсь счастливый). 
Долго мучился с решением, поставил дома точно такую же систему, нашел где-то исходник создания БД и начал заново. Только теперь я решил зайти с другой стороны.
Я решил, что может стоит попробовать сначала закачать в БД, какие-либо данные в таблицу с blob полем.  В Microsoft SQL Manager Studio сделал простой запрос на вставку данных, типа такого:

```
INSERT INTO [rs].[dbo].[Prilog]([UkID], [Name], [Kind], [File], [DelFlag] )
VALUES ( '1', 'fileName.txt','.txt','some text........', '0')
```

В результате SQL MS выдал мне ошибку (дословно воспроизвести не смогу), но суть была в общем такова, что нельзя вставлять строковые(varchar) данные в blob поле, используйте функцию **CONVERT** для этого. В итоге запрос изменился в таком ключе:

```
INSERT INTO [rs].[dbo].[Prilog]([UkID],[Name], [Kind], [File], [DelFlag] )
VALUES (  '1','fileName.txt','.txt',
           CONVERT (varbinary(max), 0x".$data['hex'].",0),'0')"
```

Подсказку, почему нужно ставить **0х**, перед переменной с данными, нашел на странице мануала [php.net](http://ru.php.net/manual/ru/function.mssql-query.php#31688) 
Товарищ подсказывал, что разница между MySQL и MS SQL в данном вопросе чувствительна к типу данных, которые передаются. В первом случае, можно напрямую передавать данные и они корректно запишутся в поле blob, во втором же случае (т.е. моем) данные необходимо писать некотируемой(unquoted) шестнадцатеричной байтовой строкой. Далее простой код загрузки файлов в БД MS SQL 2008.

```
echo"
<form action='' enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post'>
<input type='file' name='userfiles' />
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload file'>
</form>"; 
if ($_FILES['userfiles']['size'] > 0){
$name = iconv("UTF-8", "Windows-1251",$_FILES['userfiles']['name']);
$tmp_name = $_FILES['userfiles']['tmp_name'];
$type = $_FILES['userfiles']['type'];
$size = $_FILES['userfiles']['size'];

$datestring = file_get_contents("$tmp_name");
$data =unpack("H*hex", $datestring);

try {
    $db = new PDO("odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server=(local);Database=rs;TRUSTED_CONNECTION=TRUE", 'UID=sa1', 'PWD=123456' );
} catch (PDOExeption $e){
    print "#rror". $e-> getMessage(). "<br/>";
    die();
}
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $insertQuery = $db->query("INSERT INTO [rs].[dbo].[Prilog]([UkID],
                                [Name], [Kind], [File], [DelFlag] )
                           VALUES (  '1',
                                     '$name',
                                     '$type',
                                      CONVERT (varbinary(max), 0x".$data['hex'].",0),
                                     '0')");
} else echo "have not data from submit filed"; } else echo "problem with ".$_FILES['userfiles']['error'];
```

Параметр _TRUSTED_CONNECTION=TRUE_ работает только если нет рабочей группы, в моем случае на домашнем ПК эта строчка нужна, на работе же, она приводит к ошибке подключения к БД.
основные две строчки которые записывают данные в БД, это

```
$datestring = file_get_contents("$tmp_name"); //Читает содержимое файла в строку целиком
$data = unpack("H*hex", $datestring); //Распаковывает данные из бинарной строки и приводит ее к тому типу, какой будет писаться в БД.
```

Далее, в том же комменте, приводится пример скачивания данных из БД. У меня получилось так.

```
try {
$db = new PDO("odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server=(local);Database=rs;TRUSTED_CONNECTION=TRUE", 'UID=sa1', 'PWD=123456' );
} catch (PDOExeption $e){
print "#rror". $e-> getMessage(). "<br/>";
die();
}
$result = $db->query("SELECT [Name], [Kind], CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), [File],0) as 'data' FROM [rs].[dbo].[Prilog] WHERE UkID = 1")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($result as $item) {
  $name =  iconv("Windows-1251", "UTF-8",$item['Name']); //в данном случае функция iconv() лишняя
  $data = $item['data'];

$fp = fopen($name, "wb");
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
}
```

Тут вроде, все по стандартной схеме, кроме запроса данных из базы. В данном случае идет обратная конвертация из *varbinary(max)* в *varchar(max)*, чтобы получить файл в исходной кодировке. 
Единственно пока не решил вопрос с русскоязычными названиями файлов, они(названия) скачиваются в исходной кодировке и функцией iconv() это не решается. Если у кого есть мысли как это решить, буду рад помощи.

P.S.Вопрос с кириллическими именами тоже решен, так как после конвертации в запросе, данные поступают в виде *nvarchar*, то и переводить их в другую кодировку не надо (я это делал функцией iconv())

Отдельно спасибо @teran за активную помощь. Видимо все-таки разница работы версий 2008 и 2012 MS SQL в данном случае существенна, судя по всему MS SQL 2012 это делает без лишних манипуляций с функцией **CONVERT**

Answer (score 1):

Для интереса попробовал таки скачать картинку из базы.

- БД SQL Server 2012
- локально apache 2.4 (openserver), php 5.6 и 7.x,
- на сервере IIS 7.5 php 5.6

Тестовый код:

```
$st = $dbh->query("select top 1 id, imageLogo from RB_Profession");
$st->bindColumn('imageLogo', $img, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);

header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
//header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.jpeg;");

echo hex2bin($img);
```

картинка выдается (и сохраняется если раскоментить строку) вполне успешно.

как вариант

```
echo pack("H*", $img);
```

*зы: не проверял,что из них быстрее.*

---

видимо для совместимости с mysql надо сделать как-то так

```
if(is_string($img)){
    echo hex2bin($img);
}
else fpassthru($img);
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70043/discussion-on-answer-by-teran------ms-sql-).